# Exception while running Spring boot cassandra project

Tags: cassandra, spring-boot

I downloaded the spring initializer project by selecting few dependencies for web, security, validation and spring-boot cassandra. When I try to run the ./gradlew bootrun I'm getting the following exception during startup

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>       at com.anirudh.myretail.CassandratestApplication.main(CassandratestApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:240) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:86) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1429) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:162) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core..connectAsync(Cluster.java:341) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:314) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:252) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82) ~[spring-cql-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces

The Cassandra Java Driver Spring Data is using is **2.1.9**

The Cassandra version you're using is probably **3.x**. Since **3.x** all the meta data has been moved to keyspace **system_schema**

The solution to your issue are:

- downgrade your version to Cassandra **2.2.x** or **2.1.x**
- wait for Spring Data Cassandra to upgrade the driver version to
  **3.0.0**
- if you don't want to wait, use [Achilles 5.2.0](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki) which is an object
  mapper that support Cassandra **3.x**. *Note: I'm the creator of **Achilles***
- if you don't want to wait, use the [driver-mapper](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/manual/object_mapper/using) module that
  comes with the Cassandra Java Driver

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing assistance. I just downgraded the version of cassandra and it worked. I will also try to use Achillies 4.1.0 with cassandra 3.x to fix the issue.

Comment: how to use driver-mapper module to get rid of this error? I have included the cassandra-driver-mapper in the pom.xml . Is there any additional configuration needs to be done?